# How to consume Web Service in Asp.Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, web-services

I am using Asp.net Core 3.1 in Visual studio 2022. I have WSDL file only. And I have to consume the webservice. For now I don't have asmx file. I don't know how to consume such a web service through WSDL file.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to consume such a web service through WSDL file.

Well, for `Web Service` integration within the `asp.net core project` regardless of version there are two [`prerequisite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide#how-to-use-the-extension):

**Prerequisite:**

1. Either your [`web service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/write-web-service#consume-a-web-service) must be running and `URL` should available for calling
2. Or must have Valid `WSDL` file in local machine.

**Common Implementation For Both:**

Following steps would be same for both `asmx` and `wsdl` integration.

In addition, please be sure that, I have used `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022`
`Version 17.3.6` while preparing this answer.

***Step:1***

[image]

***Step:2***

[image]

***Step:3***

[image]

**Implementation Using asmx URL:**

[image]

**Note:** If your `Web Service` up and running it will start adding the reference without any issue.

**Implementation Using WSDL file:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You should `select path` for your `valid wsdl file` here. Ignore my files here, you outght to choose your `wsdl file` instead.

If you still encounter any further issue for integration you could [`refer to our official document for more details here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide#how-to-use-the-extension)